# Allowing "visible overflow" on my animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Sorry in advance if I didn't use the right words for this question. I don't know what else to call it.

I have a bunch of divs which are circles made from css, displayed inline. When they are clicked (one by one from left to right), they are animated to sort of "pop up", as in they will quickly enlarge and then shrink back to original size.

The animation works fine and all, but the problem is that when one circle animates, it is also shifting the whole line of divs (circles) along with it. **I would like my animation to appear so that the dots look like they are on a straight line (think of it as a train line) and it enlarges and shrinks without shifting the whole line**.

I have tried creating a div wrapper around all the dots, but it did not fix the problem. I have also tried tweaking some options on my animation (more specifically `overflow`). How can I fix this issue?

**Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/937mY/)**

Comment: You have to change the logic. With the relative divs, I dont think you can do this. Have to use absolute positioning.

Comment: How's this: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/937mY/9/

Comment: @Pete that looks closer to what the OP wants. You should put that in an answer. Maybe look into putting a container around each circle and overflowing out of that for the circle... that might stop the horizontal pushing.

Comment: I suggest this http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/65JEq/ I have changed relative to absolute positioning.

**HTML**

```
<div id='dots'></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {

    var gCurrentDot = 1;

    var str = '<div id="1" class="full-circle"></div><span></span>';
    for(var i=2; i<=10; i++) {
        str += '&#8213;<div id="'+(i)+'" class="full-circle"></div><span></span>';
        $('#'+ i).css({left: i*10});
    }
    $("#dots").html(str);

    $('.full-circle').click(function() {
        $('#'+ gCurrentDot +'').addClass('full-circle-green').animate({height: "30px", width:"30px",marginLeft:"-10px",marginTop:"-5px"}, {duration: 200, complete:function() {
            $(this).animate({height: "10px", width:"10px",marginLeft:"0px",marginTop:"5px"}, {duration: 200});
        }});
        gCurrentDot++;
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.full-circle {
 background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 100);
 border: 5px solid #333;
 border-radius:50%;
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius:15px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:5px;
}

.full-circle-green {
 background-color: rgba(11, 227, 0, 100);
 border: 5px solid #333;
 border-radius:50%;
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius:15px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
}

#dots span {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya i completly agreen with @sajithnair so you have to do absolute positioning

[Check out here](http://jsfiddle.net/937mY/8/)

just like this i have used absolute positioning and its done all you have to do is now add ***-*** between dots

Just CHanged your css like this

```
.full-circle {
 background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 100);
 border: 5px solid #333;
 border-radius:50%;
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius:15px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 top:5px;
}

.full-circle-green {
 background-color: rgba(11, 227, 0, 100);
 border: 5px solid #333;
 border-radius:50%;
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius:15px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 top:5px;
```

Comment: There seems to be some misalignment issues here but I guess that could be easily fixed when I read up about absolute positioning. I have a question though: where have the **-** went in the JSFiddle? Are they in the background of the dots? Thank you anyway!

Comment: no its below them you just have to increase width of theirs

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS

```
 .test{ position:absolute;}
 .wrapper{ position:relative}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="1" class="full-circle"></div>&#8213;
  <div id="2" class="full-circle"></div>&#8213;
  <div id="3" class="full-circle"></div>&#8213;
  <div id="4" class="full-circle"></div>&#8213;
  <div id="5" class="full-circle"></div>&#8213;
  <div id="6" class="full-circle"></div>&#8213;
  <div id="7" class="full-circle"></div>&#8213;
  <div id="8" class="full-circle"></div>&#8213;
  <div id="9" class="full-circle"></div>&#8213;
  <div id="10" class="full-circle"></div>
</div>
```

add new wrapper div

SCRIPT

```
var gCurrentDot = 1;

$('.full-circle').click(function() {
   var pos = $('#'+ gCurrentDot +'').position();
   var posLeft = pos.left;
   var posTop = pos.top; 

   $('body').append('<div class="full-circle-green test"></div>');
   $('.test').css('left',posLeft).css('top',posTop).animate({height: "30px", width:"30px"}, {duration: 200, complete:function() {
        $(this).animate({height: "10px", width:"10px"}, {duration: 500});
    }});

         setTimeout(function () {
             $('.test').remove();
            $('#'+ gCurrentDot +'').addClass('full-circle-green');
             gCurrentDot++;
        }, 500);

});
```